# Como Justificar en bootstrap 4. Varios elementos sobre un background-image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background, frontend

Debo justificar varios elementos sobre una imagen de fondo con bootstrap para que me queden los elementos de manera descente. Tengo que incluir 2 botones con imagenes en el centro y 3 bottones con imagenes abajo a la izquierda. para hacer una landig page de un videojuego. ahora estan así: [image: imagen actual de mi proyecto]
el codigo que estoy usando es:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("https://ucarecdn.com/270622e8-3009-4eb2-b2f1-a1f392ac57ea/CryptoBurgersBackground37x.png");
    
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
  
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Crypto Burgers</title>
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-lg px-5 " href="#" role="button"><img src="https://ucarecdn.com/a3a8f42d-a496-4310-b028-cbb4433305eb/BOTONWP2.png" height="30" alt="USA flag"></a>
        <a class="btn btn-lg px-5" href="#" role="button"><img src="https://ucarecdn.com/e37a83f4-b943-498b-b2f5-ee82067daa9f/BOTONPLAY2.png" height="30" alt="USA flag"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bg">   
    </div>
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-lg px-3 btn-primary" href="#" role="button"><img src="https://ucarecdn.com/4492dba6-f3ba-435f-a7c2-fc00d39a7012/telegrama.png" height="30" alt="USA flag"></a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg px-3 btn-primary" href="#" role="button"><img src="https://ucarecdn.com/1b7819f1-9fc0-49b2-b14d-92c6c8c7ce8e/gorjeo.png" height="30" alt="USA flag"></a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg px-3 btn-primary" href="#" role="button"><img src="https://ucarecdn.com/7021fe83-5d65-48c4-a9c7-b647cc082343/discordia.png" height="30" alt="USA flag"></a>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estás complicando mucho la vida al separar de ese modo las secciones.

Si quieres usar un `background`, deberías aplicarlo al body, no a una seccion de este.
Y así poder trabajar los botones sobre este mismo.

***HAZ CLICK EN EJECUTAR Y VER A PAGINA COMPLETA***

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://ucarecdn.com/270622e8-3009-4eb2-b2f1-a1f392ac57ea/CryptoBurgersBackground37x.png");
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Crypto Burgers</title>
  <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a class="btn btn-lg" href="#" role="button">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/a3a8f42d-a496-4310-b028-cbb4433305eb/BOTONWP2.png" height="50px" alt="USA flag">
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg" href="#" role="button">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/e37a83f4-b943-498b-b2f5-ee82067daa9f/BOTONPLAY2.png" height="50px" alt="USA flag">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
    <a class="btn btn-lg px-3 btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/4492dba6-f3ba-435f-a7c2-fc00d39a7012/telegrama.png" height="30" alt="USA flag">
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg px-3 btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/1b7819f1-9fc0-49b2-b14d-92c6c8c7ce8e/gorjeo.png" height="30" alt="USA flag">
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-lg px-3 btn-primary" href="#" role="button">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/7021fe83-5d65-48c4-a9c7-b647cc082343/discordia.png" height="30" alt="USA flag">
    </a>
  </div>

</body>
```